# Question regarding the notation $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

So my question arose while I was trying to prove this(I'm not even sure if this holds or not):
$$\int\frac{d}{dt}f(\sqrt{t})dt=f(\sqrt{t})+C$$
At first, I thought that this equation holds. But then I thought something wasn't rigorous enough. My answer included the following equation:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(\sqrt{t})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}f'(\sqrt{t})$$
Is this equation right? If it is, what does $f'(\sqrt{t})$ exactly mean? My teacher told me that I shouldn't write it like this, since it might be interpreted as below:
$$f'(\sqrt{t})=\frac{d}{dt}f(\sqrt{t})$$
But I intended it to mean:
$$f'(\sqrt{t})=\frac{d}{d\sqrt{t}}f(\sqrt{t})$$
Was I abusing the notation? If I was, how can I prove it rigorously? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would approve your notation.

With $f(x)=\sin x$, I would interpret $f'(\sqrt{t}) =\cos(\sqrt{t})$ and $$\frac{d}{dt} f(\sqrt{t})= (f(\sqrt{t}))' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}f'(\sqrt{t})= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \cos(\sqrt{t}).$$

If you don't distinguish variable names then it may be more precise to write $\frac{d}{dt} (f(\sqrt{t}))$ instead of $\frac{d}{dt} f(\sqrt{t})$ to emphasize that the derivative is taken for the whole expression. But for $f'(...)$ there is usually only one convention.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it :)